# JQuery Dialog Button Css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have  code like this:

```
 $("#confirm").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: 'Confirm',
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 550,
                buttons: [{
                    tabIndex: -1,

                    text: 'Yes',
                    "class": 'informationLearnButton',           
                    click: function () {
                       ...
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                    {

                        tabIndex: -1,
                        text: 'No',
                        'className': 'SomeOtherCssClass',
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
            });
```

class doesn't work for me i tried with class ,className with "" and without "" .
JQuery version is 1.8.22.
What to do now

Comment: using `'class'` seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cyBHq/1/

Comment: See this post :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828010/apply-css-to-jquery-dialog-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample for you how to use class:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jjdtG/104/)**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
            //do something
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    create:function () {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button:first").addClass("custom");
    }
});
```