# Adding a class to some javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, button

I'm trying to make some edits to a form written in javascript, however I'm really just getting acquainted with this language.  I'm trying to format a couple of buttons; to do this, I would like to add a class to them.  The buttons in question are "Add" and "Cancel" and they are rendered with the following function:

```
    showAddDialog: function() {
        $("#dialog").data("product",upsmart.products.pcounter);
        $("#dialog").html(upsmart.products.createForm(upsmart.products.pcounter));
        $("#photo_button").click(open_media_library);
        upsmart.products.pcounter++;
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add": upsmart.products.addProduct,
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

How might I accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            "class": 'cancelButtonClass',
            click: function() {
                // Cancel code here
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Save",
            "class": 'saveButtonClass',
            click: function() {
                // Save code here
            }
        }
    ],
    close: function() {
        // Close code here (incidentally, same as Cancel code)
    }
});
```

Source:[Apply CSS to jQuery Dialog Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828010/apply-css-to-jquery-dialog-buttons)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Worked when I tried it for just "cancel" but not when I added "add"  Here's what I've got:   $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
    {
     text: "Cancel",
     "class": 'cancelButtonClass',
     click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
     }
    },
    {
     text: "Add"
     "class": 'addButtonClass',
     click: function(){
      upsmart.products.addProduct,
     }
    }
    ],
    close: function(); {
     $(this).dialog("close");
    }
   });

Comment: Actually here, the code I pasted in my previous comment is atrocious to read.  Here's a txt so you don't have to strain your eyes: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/add.txt

Answer (score 0):

you can add class to any element using jQuery -

```
$(element).addClass("class-name")
```

if button id is `abc` you can use -

```
$("#abc").addClass("class-name")
```

[More about add classes using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

And in your specific case of `jQuery dialog` use -

```
   $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        dialogClass
       buttons: [
    {
        text: "Add",
        "class": 'addButtonClass',
        click: function() {
            // Cancel code here
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        "class": 'CancelButtonClass',
        click: function() {
            // Save code here
        }
    }
]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'd read this online but am unsure as to how to implement it for the buttons "Add" and "Cancel."  Could you give me a hint as to how I'd make use of it in this specific situation?

Comment: Thanks for the update and explanation, I tried your suggestion and it wouldn't run.  I'm assuming the code above for my specific case should work if copied verbatim into $("#dialog").dialog({