# How can i add background color to button area only?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

if i add `background:#e7eef9;` to `jQuery("#div_element").dialog`, this will be appended to whole dialog. How can i append this to `buttons` area only?

```
function test(buttonEl)
{
    jQuery("#div_element").dialog({
         resizable: false,
         height:200,
         modal: true,
         width: 300,
         buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                 jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply CSS to jQuery Dialog Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828010/apply-css-to-jquery-dialog-buttons)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~`.

CSS:

```
#div_element ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
    background: e7eef9;
}
```